# Ocultar formulario apos fazer upload de um arquivo

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Olá,
Eu tenho uma view que tem mais de um formulário e em cada formulário, eu especifico o tipo de documento que será feito upload. ex: form1 tem um input hidden com value = 1, para cpf... form2 value = 2, para rg... etc...
Assim na hora que dou um post para servidor pego esse value e salvo o arquivo convertido em base64 no banco com o nome do tipo do documento: no caso 1, como cpf.
Tudo que quero, e não sei como fazer... é quando post for finalizado e, ao retornar a view dos formularios, o form1 seja ocultado.

> Minha View

```
@model BancoBBB.Models.Anexo

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Anexar";
    Layout = "~/Views/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Anexar</h2>
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


<div class="col col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    
    <form action="/Anexo/Upload" class="form-horizontal form-label-left" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="frmCpf" method="post" name="frmCpf">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <label>CPF</label>
                <input type="hidden" value="1" name="TipoDocumento" id="TipoDocumento" />
                <input id="File" type="file" name="File" class="form-control" />
            </div>

            <div class="col-3" style="padding-top:25px;">

                <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" />

            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Anexo", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "form-horizontal form-label-left", name = "frmRg" }))
    {

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <label>RG</label>
                <input type="hidden" value="2" name="TipoDocumento" id="TipoDocumento" />
                <input id="File" type="file" name="File" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-3" style="padding-top:25px;">
                <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" />
            </div>
        </div>
    }

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Anexo", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "form-horizontal form-label-left", name = "frmRes" }))
    {

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <label>Comprovante de Residência</label>
                <input type="hidden" value="3" name="TipoDocumento" id="TipoDocumento" />
                <input id="File" type="file" name="File" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-3" style="padding-top:25px;">
                <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" />
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>

<div class="row">
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

> Minha Model

```
    {
        public int AnexoId { get; set; }
        public Documento TipoDocumento { get; set; }// Classe enum
        public string Arquivo { get; set; }//Propriedade que vai receber a conversão para base64
        public string Formato { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
    } 

    public enum Documento
    {
        Cpf = 1,
        Rg = 2,
        ComprovanteResidencia = 3,
    }
```

> Controller Anexo

```
public ActionResult Anexar()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Upload(Anexo anexo)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                anexo.Arquivo = ConverterArquivoBase64(anexo.File);
                anexo.Formato = anexo.File.ContentType;
                anexoDao.Salvar(anexo);
                return RedirectToAction("Anexar");
            }
            return View("Anexar");
        }

        public static string ConverterArquivoBase64(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            byte[] arquivo = new byte[pdf.ContentLength];
            file.InputStream.Read(arquivo, 0, file.ContentLength);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(arquivo);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sua aplicação está meio confusa, eu não teria dois forms na mesma view apenas para separar o tipo do documento, mas uma forma de resolver esta sua situação é sempre passar um modelo para seu view, e no retorno vc indicar para o modelo quem vc quer ocultar. no caso a primeira vez, a propriedade seria nula, e vc não ocultaria.

ex.
no cshtm
@model MeuModelo

no controller

return View("Anexar", MeuModelo);